# Automatically adding a row to a gridview when certain conditions are present

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a row to a gridview which has AutoGenerateColumns="true". Here is the trick though. The SQL query is written in such way (using pivot) that it returns records in groups of three as depicted below:

```
Repair Code Repair Code Entries 6/1/2012    7/1/2012    8/1/2012    9/1/2012
00000A  Critical Down Time          1       
00000A  Critical Outage             1       
00000A  Total Repair Time          65       
00000B  Critical Down Time                                              6
00000B  Critical Outage                                                 3
00000B  Total Repair Time                                              90
00000C  Critical Down Time          1                      5    
00000C  Critical Outage             1                      5    
00000C  Total Repair Time          30                    240    
00000D  Critical Down Time                                 2     
00000E  Critical Down Time                                 1    
00000G  Critical Down Time                                 1    
00000M  Critical Down Time          1                      3    
00000M  Critical Outage             1                      3    
00000M  Total Repair Time          60                    180
```

I need to add a blank row between 00000A and XYXYXY. The GridView is populated from a bll class using a DataTable. I'm utilizing the OnRowCreated method to modify the column headers and OnRowDataBound to format the information in the cell.

I thought I could add a row in eihter of the two event methods but it seems to me that it would be too late in the cycle. I'm I right?

I've come across various posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982744/add-row-to-asp-net-gridview) and [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/467788/Dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-from-ASP-NET) but they all going about it in a diferrent way such as a button click event.

In my case the only constant that I can depend on are the presence or absense of the three categories: the down time, repair time and total. There are instances where I only have one or two of the three categories and this is where I need to insert a row with corresponding missing category.

Any suggestions how to to go about it?

Thanks,

R.

UPDATE: I've updated the output from the query above. As you see in the lower half "Critical Down Time" is repeaded 4 times so I need to intercept the data and add "Critical Outage", "Total Repair Time", and a blank row as separator.

Comment: Add the row in the `DataTable` instead

Comment: All my DataTable code looks like this: DataTable dt = null; dt = CLASS.METHOD(PARAM1, PARAM2,...); gv.DataSource = dt; and DataBind(); How can a row be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a new row to the `DataTable`. Like so:

First, find the index where you want to insert the new row. This is done using the primary key of the row (I am assuming your rows have primary keys)

```
int rowPosition = dt.Rows.IndexOf(dt.Rows.Find([PRIMARY KEY]));
```

Then create a new row and insert it into the table:

```
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(), rowPosition);
```

Then, you can bind the GridView the same way as before.

**UPDATE**

After receiving some more updates from OP, here is the solution:

First, some variables.

```
/// <summary>
/// This holds the number and names of the subcategories that are required for each category. 
/// </summary>
string[] subCategories = new string[3] { "Critical Down Time", "Critical Outage", "Total Repair Time" };
string categoryPrevious = null;
string categoryCurrent = null;
int subCategoryOccurences = 0;
int rowCount = 0;
DataRow rowFiller = null;
```

Here is the method that receives the datatable after it is populated from the database.

```
public void PrepareDataTable(DataTable dtResults)
{

    if (dtResults == null || dtResults.Rows.Count == 0)
        return;

    //initialize category
    categoryPrevious = dtResults.Rows[0]["Category"].ToString();
    do
    {
        //get the current category
        categoryCurrent = dtResults.Rows[rowCount]["Category"].ToString();
        //check if this is a new category. this is where all the work is done
        if (categoryCurrent != categoryPrevious)
        {
            //check if we have fulfilled the requirement for number of subcategories 
            CheckSubCategoryRequirements(dtResults);
            //at this point we have fulfilled the requirement for number of subcategories 
            //add blank (separator) row
            dtResults.Rows.InsertAt(dtResults.NewRow(), rowCount);
            rowCount++;
            //reset the number of subcategories
            subCategoryOccurences = 0;
            categoryPrevious = categoryCurrent;
        }
        else
        {
            rowCount++;
            categoryOccurences++;
        }
    } while (rowCount < dtResults.Rows.Count);
    //check sub category requirements for the last category
    CheckSubCategoryRequirements(dtResults);

}
```

This is the method that handles adding any missing subcategories. I have extracted the code into a separate method because it is called in two separate places in the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks if a category has fulfilled the requirements for # of sub categories and adds the missing sub categories, if needed
/// </summary>
private void CheckSubCategoryRequirements(DataTable dtResults)
{
    if (subCategoryOccurences< subCategories.Length)
    {
        //we need to add rows for the missing subcategories
        while (subCategoryOccurences< subCategories.Length)
        {
            //create a new row and populate category and subcategory info
            rowFiller = dtResults.NewRow();
            rowFiller["Category"] = categoryPrevious;
            rowFiller["SubCategory"] = subCategories[subCategoryOccurences];
            //insert the new row into the current location of table 
            dtResults.Rows.InsertAt(rowFiller, rowCount);
            subCategoryOccurences++;
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here is a "test harness" to test the above code:

```
public void RunTest()
{
    DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
    dtResults.Columns.Add("Category");
    dtResults.Columns.Add("SubCategory");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("XXXX", "Critical Down Time");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("XXXX", "Critical Outage");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("XXXX", "Total Repair Time");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("YYYY", "Critical Down Time");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("YYYY", "Critical Outage");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("ZZZZ", "Critical Down Time");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("ZZZZ", "Critical Outage");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("ZZZZ", "Total Repair Time");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("AAAA", "Critical Down Time");

    PrepareDataTable(dtResults);
}
```

I have tested the code and it seems to be working per your requirements. Let me know if I missed something or if any part is unclear.

Here is the before and after of the datatable:

Before

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: I guess the the question remains where in the events or lifecycle I need to do this? And no, rows have no PK - the sproc query consist of a PIVOT statement which gets data from a view that has another three views joined in a UNION. I've posted it once a while back but I think it either scared people away or thought I was nuts and no one replied. I can post the code but it will have to be tommorow morning.

Comment: @Risho You add the row to the `DataTable` before you bind it to the grid. You need to do nothing with the `GridView`.

Comment: If you don't have a primary key, it is still doable, just a little more cumbersome. Quick question. Is the use case ALWAYS to add a row between "00000A" and "XYXYXY", or is it more general like: I want to add a blank row between "sections"? By sections, I am referring to rows that have the same value for the first column.

Comment: @ShaiCohen: The requirement is to have all three categories displayed. The query doesn't always retur all three. You could have a row such as 000000A | Critical Down Time |....., followed by the next row of XYXYXYX | Critical Donw Time |....., in which case, I need to insert three rows immediatelly below, adding "Critical Outage", "Total Repair time" and a blank row to delineate the group. Another words, always want to add the missing row category without values. Are you following me?

Comment: @Magnus: As I've tried to explain to ShaiCohen, I have to display the three categories and if the query doesn't provide it, I have insert it manually. So if you're saying that I need to do this before the bind then I understand that. But how exactly do I "open" up the record set, iterate thru the rows to see if I have the triplet of rows and if I don't how do I insert the row I need?

Comment: @Risho: OK that makes sense. Another question. Are "00000A" and "XYXYXY" always returned or could this change? Can one be missing? Can another be added? Is the number of "groups" always the same or will there be cases where the groups (number and title) change? BTW, don't get disheartened, all this is very doable. I just want to understand the requirements fully before posting another answer.

Comment: @ShaiCohen: Yes the "00000A" and "XYXYXY" are always returned. If the row isn't returned, that is because the there are no values after the second column. The "groups" have to be displayed in threes, alway the same wording. If there is not data than naturally the group is reduced by that number of rows and so that is the instance where I need insert the row with the otherwise missing wording.

Comment: @ShaiCohen: WOW!!! That is a lot of work you've put in! And I can't thank you enough. Code throws a NoNullAllowedException on the SubCategory column. I'm looking into fixing that.

Comment: @Risho: You are very welcome. I always love a good challenge :). At what point does it throw that error? Does it throw the error using the test data I provided or using your "real" data?

Comment: @Risho: Also, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped. An upvote wouldn't hurt either ;)

Comment: @ShaiCohen, discovered an issue. In the CheckSubCategoryRequirements method when a new category is present the subCategoryOccurences counter remain at 3 thus inserting "Total Repair Time" which is third row of the previous on the first row of the current group.

Comment: @Risho: doesn't this line: `subCategoryOccurences = 0;` take care of that? Can you provide me with data that replicates this problem?

Comment: @ShaiCohen, subCategoryOccurences counter seroes out after CheckSubCategoryRequirements and it is a global vaiable. I've tried to move subCategoryOccurences = 0; before the method call but that made things worse. (I'll see if I can post data above.

Comment: @ShaiCohen, actualy if you look at the output above I have instances where for example the query does not rerun all three subcategories, it can be just one, any one of the three, or two, anyone of the three.

Comment: @Risho: From your original question, it show that "Critical Down Time" is always returned first for each category. If there is a second entry for the same category it is always "Critical Outage". And if there is a third entry for the same category it is always "Total Repair Time". Are you saying now that is not the case?

Comment: @ShaiCohen, yes, it was an oversight, I was also under the impression that we always get three categories, not matter what  - it is not so.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Here's an idea, since the comments here are getting a bit out of hand .. :)... why don't you take a little time to understand the problem in your head and post a new question. Then leave a comment with my name and I'll help you however I can. Here is a good technique that I have used many times to help me understand exactly what problem I am facing: [Rubber Ducking] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I know it sounds silly, but it works.